# Simple script using ajax and node.js, why it don't work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pushMe(elem) {            
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();               

            if (!request) alert("Error initializing XMLHttpRequest!");

            request.open('GET', 'proj1.js', true);

            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState == 4)
                    elem.value = request.responseText;
            };         
            elem.value = '...';
            request.send(null);   
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="pushMe(this);" value="Push Me!" id="btn"/>
</body>
</html>
```

and js file (proj1.js):

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');

function accept(req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    });

    res.end("HELLO!");
}

http.createServer(accept).listen(8080);
```

proj1.js and test.html are in the same folder.
Why the value of button don't change, when I click buton?
(It change, but request.responseText is empty, why it isn't "HELLO!"?)

Comment: Any error messages on the console? Did you check the network tab? Did you add a breakpoint? Please do some debugging and post your results here

Comment: Did you sucessfully install Node.js beforehand on the server?

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

### Your problem:

You are using a file in a file protocol, for example:

`file:///c:\user\index.html`

and are trying to reach a server that runs on [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) which is impossible (unless you release the security permissions of the browser, but this is not the case).

The correct is you run Ajax on an HTTP script.

### Learn the basics

Before you START programming for Web you should understand what is [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [WebServer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server), [Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_%28computing%29), [Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), [Response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request-response) and [Status Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

### Getting Started With Node.js:

http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

[Edited]

### Probable problems:

- Incorrect port being called (maybe instead of using port 8080, the ajax is calling port 80)

### Problem in your script:

- Http error untreated (Your ajax is not treating the http errors)

Try this:

```
        request.open('GET', 'proj1.js', true);

        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                if (request.status == 200) {
                    elem.value = request.responseText;
                } else {
                    elem.value = "Error:" + request.status;//Get error
                }
            }
        };
```

### Use console / webtools

Press with F12 (firefox for example), see tab "NetWork" and "Console":

Using developer tools:

- IE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools
- Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index

Comment: The first problem, I don't think the second bullet makes sense

Comment: @MamekoMikhail you used the "F12" key (developer tools) in your browser? What `console.log` returned? Can you use the `console.log`? Have you checked the ports used on the front-end to request your server?

Comment: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: 
file:///C:/.../test.html
Line 22

Comment: @MamekoMikhail There's no way you call a relative file in a "file protocol" and the browser understand that you want to catch a "http" server.

Comment: @MamekoMikhail You can't run AJAX from a local file. You have to run it from your `localhost` address

Comment: @MamekoMikhail I'm sorry, if you don't know how to load a page from your local server, you need to study up before you can try to make AJAX requests. You should post separate questions. First one, how do I load an HTML file from a locally installed Node.js server?

Comment: No @MamekoMikhail, `http://localhost/C:/.../proj1.js` is incorret, I update my answer, read the part "Getting Started With Node.js", what you need is to learn the basics before.

Comment: Before you START programming for Web you should understand what is [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol),
[WebServer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server),
[Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_%28computing%29),
[Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol),
[Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods),
[Response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request-response)
and
[Status Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).